# asmx WEBサービスでJSONを返したいがXML形式になってしまう

Tags: swift, c#, json, asp.net

.NET Framework4.5で作成したWebサービスアプリケーションでJSONを返し、
iPadからSwiftのAlamofire、SwiftyJSONで取得したいと思っています。

オブジェクトのシリアライズにはJavaScriptSerializerを使っています。

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetEmployessJSON()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=101,  
                Name="Nitin",  
                Salary=10000  
            },  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=102,  
                Name="Dinesh",  
                Salary=100000  
            }  
        };

        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(emps);
        return json;
    }
}
```

■web.config

```xml
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

<!-- Getを有効にする -->
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>      
</webServices>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

ブラウザのアドレスバーにURLを直接入力してアクセスすると、

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"Id":101,"Name":"Nitin","Salary":10000},{"Id":102,"Name":"Dinesh","Salary":100000}]</string>

このようにXML形式で返ってきて、中身がJsonという状態になってしまいます。
純粋にJsonだけを返したいのですが、何か解決策はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そもそも自分でシリアライズするならWEBサービスである必要はないと思いますが
WEBフォームで

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {  
        new Employee()  
        {  
            Id=101,  
            Name="Nitin",  
            Salary=10000  
        },  
        new Employee()  
        {  
            Id=102,  
            Name="Dinesh",  
            Salary=100000  
        }  
    };

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = serializer.Serialize(emps);
    Response.Write(json);
    Response.End();
}
```

でいけるんじゃ

WEBサービスでやるなら、すでに回答されてるようにEmployee[]を戻せばよいはずです

```
public Employee[] GetEmployessJSON()
{
    Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {  
        new Employee()  
        {  
            Id=101,  
            Name="Nitin",  
            Salary=10000  
        },  
        new Employee()  
        {  
            Id=102,  
            Name="Dinesh",  
            Salary=100000  
        }  
    };
    return emps;
}
```

リクエストのContent-Typeにapplication/jsonを設定する方法ですが
ページ処理が始まってる段階で設定しても遅いです
Glabal.asaxで

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.PathInfo == "/GetEmployessJSON")
    {
        Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
}
```

とかやってやればいけるはずです

Answer (score 2):

JSON形式でASMXを呼び出すためにはリクエストの`Content-Type`を`application/json`にする必要があります。
またサーバー側は明示的にJSONに変換する必要は無く、戻り値の型は`Employee[]`で良いと思われます。

なおweb.configでハンドラーを弄れば`Content-Type`を明示しなくてもJSONが既定の形式になったと思いますが、統合モードで可能かはわかりません。

Comment: リクエストのContent-Typeをapplication/jsonにして試しましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。
また、web.configを下記を参考に修正しましたが変わりませんでした。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743562/create-basic-webservice-for-json-response-in-asp-net
単純にブラウザのアドレスバーにURLを直接入力した時に、下記の様に出力されることを期待しています。
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&media=software

Comment: @reo ブラウザでURLを入力して実行した場合は通常Content-Typeが指定されないため、JSON形式にはなりません。クライアントからPOSTしてみて下さい。

Comment: アプリからContent-Typeを指定してPOSTしましたが解消しませんでした。GETで取得したいため、サーバ側でContent-Typeを指定しました。

Answer (score 2):

GetEmployessJSON() はjsonとしてシリアライズした結果の文字列を返していますが、
これをEmployeeのListをそのまま返すように変更したらどうなりますか？

[Getting Json data using jQuery and .ASMX web services.](https://cmatskas.com/getting-json-data-using-an-asmx-web-service/)

Comment: 戻り値の型をEmployee[]として、return emps;とすると、XMLが表示されました。

Answer (score 1):

下記のようにContentTypeを指定することで解消できました。

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public Employee[] GetEmployessXML()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=101,  
                Name="Nitin",  
                Salary=10000  
            },  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=102,  
                Name="Dinesh",  
                Salary=100000  
            }  
        };
        return emps;
    }


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetEmployessJSON()
    {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=101,  
                Name="Nitin",  
                Salary=10000  
            },  
            new Employee()  
            {  
                Id=102,  
                Name="Dinesh",  
                Salary=100000  
            }  
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(emps));
    }
}
```